# Why does 'this' refer to the jQuery object when it is called in a xxx.click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some exercises on bind, and I have a stupid question regarding jquery's click function. Why is it when I pass in a method to click, 'this' points to the jquery object that click was triggered on, but when I pass in an anonymous function, this doesn't happen? I understand that if 'this' refers to the jquery object then we need to use bind, but don't understand why 'this' changes.

```
var test = {
    data: 'Hello World',
    getData: function() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }    
};
//Base case - calling a method on an object
test.getData();

//test 1 -> doesn't work
$('#test1').click(test.getData);

//test2 -> works
$('#test2').click(test.getData.bind(test));

//test3 -> works
$('#test3').click(function(event) {
    test.getData();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17h6h4yq/

Comment: Technically, `this` is not bound to the jQuery object but to the underlying DOM element.

Comment: Because that's how `this` works. Learn more about it from the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: jQuery explicitly maps `this` to the appropriate element for you. Even if you use event delegation and bind the click event to `document`, jQuery changes `this` to the element it's delegated from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `this` in a click function is the element clicked.

So this line :

```
$('#test1').click(test.getData);
```

Convert the `this` inside your function to `#test1`.

This line :

```
$('#test2').click(test.getData.bind(test));
```

You are using bind which change the `this` to the first parameter sent. In this case : the object `test`.

And this line:

```
$('#test3').click(function(event) {
    test.getData();
});
```

You have a function that launch an other function. The clicked element (mentioned in the first snippet) is passed to the first function.

```
$('#test3').click(function(event) {
    console.log(this); //`#test3`
    test.getData();
});
```

So `text.getData()` `this` value is not changed, it is the orignal. In other word, `this` will be the object `test`.

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes a lot of sense! For test3, why does 'this' refer to #test3 inside the anonymous function -> why wouldn't it refer to the global window (for instance, 'this' in a standalone function within a method refers to the global window)

Comment: @DanTang: Because jQuery sets `this` in the event handler to the element the handler is bound to. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/#stoppropagation

Comment: @DanTang `this` is determined anew each time the function is *called*, not when it is declared. If you declared `function foo(){}` and then assigned it to `myobj.bar = foo`, and you used `foo` and `myobj.bar` as event listeners, they would both have a `this` of the event target when run. If doesn't matter that the function is attached to an object as a method or not. The function object itself that you pass into `click` has no idea if it's a method; it's just a list of instructions. When you *call* `myobj.bar()`, then the function is told it should have a `this` of `myobj` at call time.

Comment: Nothing to add, well said.

Comment: #apsillers thank you, I understand now. Basically it's akin to `document.getElementById('test3').onclick = function fn()...` this within fn will refer to `doucment.getElementById('test3')`.